# Seeking clarification of conditional statement operations

Tags: python, conditional-statements

The conditional statement
in the code, below, is confusing me slightly.

It pretty much asks the user for numbers,
then tells you which is the smallest/largest.

My issue here is that I'm  confused as to why the conditional statement part looks the way it looks?
Specifically, how does the code save and compare largest to smallest?

```py
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
   num = input('Enter Number: ')
   if num == 'done':
   break
try:
    num = int(num)
except:
    print("Invalid input")
    continue

if largest is None:
    largest = num
elif largest < num:
    largest = num
if smallest is None:
    smallest = num
elif num < smallest:
    smallest = num

print('Maximum is', largest)
print('Minimum is', smallest)
```

Comment: Some help: https://realpython.com/python-conditional-statements/. Also, your code is incorrectly indented (or you have accidentally done that when posting your question). [Indentation is very important in Python](https://realpython.com/python-conditional-statements/#grouping-statements-indentation-and-blocks).

Comment: @jarmod Nice link!

Comment: @jarmod, yeah the indent is only due to posting the question :) 
the code works nicely 
was just wandering how the code stores the values and tells the difference between smallest and largest

Comment: You should correct the posted code in that case. At present, it's incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually these are two `if … elif` chains. You can read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html).

```py
    if largest is None:
        largest = num
    elif largest < num:
        largest = num

    if smallest is None:
        smallest = num
    elif num < smallest:
        smallest = num
```

At first, execution will go into the first one and check if `largest` is `None`. If it is, `num`'s value vill be assigned to largest. (So the number from `num` will be saved in the `largest` variable.) If it's not, then it will verify if `largest` is less then num. Of this is true, then the number will be saved again. Otherwise nothing will be saved in this chain.

All the same in the second chain, except that we check if this number is the smallest of the numbers entered.

All other is mostly a wrap around this code, that provides a numbers to this chains to process them.

First two lines set the initial states of variables to store the largest and the smallest number entered.

```py
largest = None
smallest = None
```

Then it goes the `while` loop. As it has `True` as condition, it will be infinit loop (no stop condition, untill something interrupts it).

```py
while True:
```

Here we have an input request and receiving. Input will be saved to the `num` variable. If word "done" was entered, then loop will be interruped and script will execute the code below the loop.

```py
    num = input('Enter Number: ')
    if num == 'done':
    break
```

Here we check if number was entered. If it's not a number, then "Invalif input" will be prined and we go to the next iteration of the loop (because of `continue`). So user get the input prompt again.

```py
    try:
        num = int(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue
```

At the end of the script (when the loop was interrupted) the largest and the smallest number will be printed.

```py
print('Maximum is', largest)
print('Minimum is', smallest)
```

Comment: so the way the code 'saves' the value of num is due to the fact that it initially saves it as 'None', then compares to new input value?

Comment: @DrFaraday Because it's a chain of conditions. `elif` you can expand as `then` and nested `if`. So if first condition (next to `if`) is true (evaluated to `True`) then second (next to `elif`) is not evaluted, as it lies below `then`.

Comment: @DrFaraday Updated to describe work of the script more in details.